# Show that the set $A = \{x \in X : n < d(x,b) < N\}$ is an open set as follows.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $b \in X$. Let $n,N \in \Bbb R$ such that $0<n<N.$
Show that the set
\begin{equation*}
A = \{x \in X : n < d(x,b) < N\}
\end{equation*}
is open in $X$.

**Attempt:**

**Theorem.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $k$ be a positive integer. If $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_k$ are open, then $\bigcap_{j=1}^k A_j$ so is.

Let $b \in X$ be arbitrary and take $n,N \in \Bbb R$ such that $0<n<N$.
Define $A_1 = \{x \in X : n < d(x,b)\}$ and $A_2 = \{x \in X : d(x,b) < N\}$ such that $A = A_1 \cap A_2$. The goal is to show that $A$ is an open set, by using the properties in metric space, which says that the intersection of finitely open sets is an open set as follows.

1. The goal is to show that $A_1$ is an open set.
   To do this, let $x \in A_1$ and $r:=d(x,b)-n>0$. We want to show that $B(x,r) \subseteq A_1$. Notice that by taking $y \in B(x,r)$, we have
   \begin{align*}
   d(y,b) \ge d(x,b) - d(x,y) > d(x,b) - r = n.
   \end{align*}
   Hence, $y \in A_1$ and so, $B(x,r) \subseteq A_1$, as desired. Moreover, $A_1$ is an open set.
2. The goal is to show that $A_2$ is an open set. To do this, let $x \in A_2$ and $s:=N-d(x,b)>0$. We want to show that $B(x,s) \subseteq A_2$. Notice that by taking $y \in B(x,s)$, we have
   \begin{align*}
   d(y,b) \le d(y,x) + d(x,b) < s + d(x,b) = N.
   \end{align*}
   Hence, $y \in A_2$ and so, $B(x,s) \subseteq A_2$, as desired. Moreover, $A_2$ is an open set.
3. Since both of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open sets, by the **Theorem** above, we have $A_1 \cap A_2$ so is.

Thus, by the above inspection, we finally have $A$ is an open set, as desired. Q.E.D.

Does the above approach correct? Does there any other simple approaches than the above? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A different approach is to use the fact that the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function  is continuous. $A=f^{-1}((n,N))$ where $f(x)=d(x,b)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the other point of view. But, does my approach correct?

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks a lot, Sir. I appreciated your comments.